# Efficient Dynamic String Creation in data.table

Tags: r, string, data.table

I have a large data table and would like to insert a column containing a string with list of variables (this list is of dynamic size).

For example, if I know that my `cols` list is of length 2, I can do this:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("Year", "City")
DT[, Cohort := paste(cols[1], get(cols[1]), ",", cols[2], get(cols[2]))]
```

However, I'd like to be able to create this string, dynamically, for any length of `cols`, using the `data.table` framework.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
DT[,Cohort:=do.call(paste,c(Map(paste,cols,.SD),list(sep=", "))),.SDcols=cols]
```